# How to generate a sequence of numbers in Hiveql in recursive way?

Tags: sql, hive, db2, hiveql

I've recently moved from DB2 to hiveql.
There's a query that I used to generate a sequence of numbers recursively, like 1 to 1000. Under is the used code;

```
WITH TB (N) AS
(VALUES (100)
UNION ALL
SELECT N + 100
FROM TB
WHERE N + 1 <= 5000)
SELECT * FROM TB;
```

I could make whatever sequence I wanted with this code,

but now in Hiveql things like `VALUES()` or `WITH TB (N)` doesn't seem to work as done in DB2.
Is there a way to generate such sequences in hiveql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate sequence in Hive using this query. `space()` returns string of spaces of given length, `split` creates an array of spaces, `posexplode` explodes an array (generates rows), you can use index for sequence generation:

```
set hivevar:start=1; --Define sequence start and end
set hivevar:end=20;

with seq as(
select posexplode(split(space(${end}-${start}),' ')) as (i,x)
)
select ${start}+i from seq;
```